# Set some GPIO pins OFF during boot, and ON later

Tags: gpio, boot, serial

I'm using  `+3.3V / GND / TX`   pins  to power [this 7-segment display](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11441) with Serial Port connection. It works, but during booting time, the display **displays random things**, probably because it receives random values on `GPIO TX`...

I would like to set the 7-segment display ON *only* when my Python code starts, and OFF by default (during booting time).

**Is there a +3.3V or +5V GPIO pin that is default to OFF (during boot), and that I can power ON with my code?**

or

**Is there a way to prevent GPIO TX to send random values during booting time?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the UART TX gpio is used during boot to log boot messages.  After boot the UART (RX/TX gpios) is used to allow login.

The simplest way on Raspbian to disable boot messages and login is by using the raspi-config option.

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Comment: Untested but you might also affect this by removing `console=ttyAMA0` from `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

Comment: I'm on Arch Linux @joan so I couldn't test `raspi-config`. What does it do? Does it do more or less do the same thing than remove `console=ttyAMA0` in `/boot/cmdline.txt`?  I tried this and it works  (except that on plugging the Pi power, there might be some 1 or 2 random characters fired to TX... How to stop that?)

Comment: raspi-config edits /boot/cmdline.txt to remove the console field as above and edits /etc/inittab to comment out the final line which spawns a login process on the serial link.  There is nothing you can do in software about the spurious power-up characters.  Also when the port is opened a spurious start bit is generated.  Again you can't do anything about that in software.

Comment: @joan What's the equivalent of `removing the final line of /etc/inittab` with systemd / archlinux ?

Comment: I have no idea.  Arch should have something similar.  The line is T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100